# Permutations on 5 letters

Tags: combinatorics

I was doing a riddle which said "five points are randomly distributed on the circumference of a circle. From any of these points, a continuous line may be drawn that connects the other points on the polygon before returning to the original point. How many different polygons can be drawn with these five points?" The answer the book gave me was 12.

Why? I thought there would be 11...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the points as $A, B, C, D, E$, and suppose that you always start and end at $A$. Then we can encode a polygon as a string such as:
$$
AEBCDA
$$
Focusing on the inner four letters, there are $4! = 24$ possible strings. But notice that we're double-counting, since traversing the points in reverse will yield the same polygon. For example, the following string also encodes the same polygon as above:
$$
ADCBEA
$$
So our final answer is $\frac{24}{2} = 12$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by choosing one point as your starting point. The remaining four points must be selected in some order. There are $4! = 24$ ways to permute these four points. This is the number of sequences starting at $p_0$ and moving to every other point. However, for every sequence, the inverse sequence is included as well. Therefore, all you need to do is divide the number you have by $2$. This, you get $4!/2 = 12$ possibilities.

[image: Points on a circle]

(Note that many of these polygons will be self-intersecting.)